# how to create time slot vector from two numeric vectors in R

Tags: r

I have stored two vectors as

```
hrs <- sample(0:23,500,replace=T)
mins<- sample(0:59,500,replace=T)
```

so my question is can we store these two vectors in `HH:MM` format in single vector in R language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
paste(hrs, mins, sep=":")
```

If we need the `HH:MM` format, use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%02d:%02d", hrs, mins)
```

Comment: Thank you very much